# Azure data transfer charging

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have blob storage  and app service  in our Azure account.
I was uploaded by app service 200GB from my local PC to blob storage.
Data has been charged (14 EUR) as DATA TRANSFER OUT - Zone 1. I don't understand why it happened.
I previously thought that this type of data transfer is IN TO Zone 1 and is free (no charged). 
I thought that all uploads to storage is free and all downloads from storage are charged.

Is it correct pricing ?

Answer (score 1):

In case you use some kind of replicated storage as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-redundancy/) the outgoing replication traffic which flows across regions will be charged to you (described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/) at the bottom).

> What is Geo-Replication Data Transfer Charge? When you write data into
>   GRS accounts, that data will be replicated to another Azure region.
>   The Geo-Replication Data Transfer charge is the bandwidth cost of
>   replicating that data to another Azure region.

Comment: But I dont have GRS account. My blob storage account is Locally-redundant storage (LRS) and all objects in my Azure account was created in the same region West Europe. Upload 1:
local App Service (out of cloud) to Locally-redundant storage (LRS) :  200GB .. 0 Eur .  Upload 2: Azure App Service (West Europe) to Locally-redundant storage (LRS) :  200GB .. 14 Eur  Why ??